# Can't read tables from firefox using Java sqlite jdbc

Tags: java, firefox, sqlite

I'm using the following code to connect and read moz_bookmarks from Java

```
 String connection = "jdbc:sqlite:/" + Tracking.FILES_LOCATION + "places.sqlite";
 Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:path_to_places.sqlite/");
 Statement stat = conn1.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery("select * from moz_bookmarks;");
```

But I keep getting : `"java.sql.SQLException: file is encrypted or is not a database"`
Even after upgrading my jdbc sqlite driver for sqlite3
Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You create a connection name in first line, but in the second line you have a connection string which is probably copied from some tutorial.

Try to use connection variable when calling getConnection method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String connection = "jdbc:sqlite:/" + Tracking.FILES_LOCATION + "places.sqlite";
Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
Statement stat = conn1.createStatement();
String Query = "select * from moz_bookmarks";
ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery(Query);
```